# How to add multiple users in bitbucket team

Tags: bitbucket

I have a long list of email that are to be added as team members. I have responses in excel sheet. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

[image]Go to Create Team in Teams dropdown, select a Team name , Team Id, Under Add Team Members enter their bitbucket username or email. After adding teammates, click on Create. This should work.

This is how u can add

Comment: Friend! I am able to achieve this easily. I want where can I write all emails (separated by comma or space) so that I have to press ADD just once.